# How do I turn on my phone if my home button doesn't work and it won't turn on at all?

Tags: iphone

I woke my phone and it was working fine till I went into apps and they weren't loading. So I shut down my phone. Well when I did that it never turned back on and now it's a black screen with a loading thing on it. I don't know what to do so can someone please help me?

Comment: Plug it in :) - an iPhone will always turn on when it's plugged in

Answer (score 2):

First try resetting the phone by holding both home and power for ~10 seconds, see if it manages to boot.

If not, plug it into a computer and see if iTunes will recognize it and offer to restore it. If it doesn't then you'll have to put the phone in recovery or DFU mode and force a restore.

This also involves pressing home and power simultaneously, but to keep pressing after the first reboot when the Apple logo comes up, while the phone is connected to a computer.
Apple provides further information [here](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201263)

Answer (score 1):

If my iphone wont turn on and after I try everything i can, then I replace the battery.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different MacKenzie! It looks like you've posted a question as an answer to someone else's problem. On this site it is preferable to create a new question each time, please consider removing this post and creating a new question.